# Receiving error message "Enterprise_Pci requires module Mage_Api"

Tags: magento-enterprise, error

I've managed to fix the previous

> error processing your request

and had the `dev` site running again. The following day, I was preparing myself to run some tests but couldn't because of the error message is back.

This time, error is different and I don't  understand what the issue is now.

> a:4:{i:0;s:51:"Module "Enterprise_Pci" requires module
>   "Mage_Api".";i:1;s:926:"#0
>   /chroot/home/vpwindow/dev.mossyoakgraphics.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(849):
>   Mage::throwException('Module "Enterpr...')

**Note:** I can not access the admin side either.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the Mage_Api module is enabled in `/app/etc/modules/Mage_Api.xml`